plsql script is raising 'ERROR at line 1 DECLARE', I don't see the reason
Good afternoon community,
I have a PLSQL script executed against ORACLE 19 that is displaying an error that I don't understand.
The script drops any existing index before recreate them.
The objects are defined in a kind-off list to prevent statement repetition

dropping an unexisting index is OK (just catch the exception and continue)
create an index that is failing should continue to create the remaining indexes to th the end

My PLSQL script is
set serveroutput on;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

DECLARE
    index_not_exists EXCEPTION;
    table_not_exists EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (index_not_exists, -1418);
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (table_not_exists, -942);

    TYPE ind_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL;
    ind_to_drop ind_list := ind_list('sst_ind1', 'sst_ind2');
    /* first index is wrong because col0 does not exist */
    ind_to_create ind_list := ind_list('create index sst_ind1 on sst_table(col0)', 'create index sst_ind2 on sst_table(col2)');

    sql_to_exec varchar(200);
    is_all_index_created boolean := TRUE;

BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table sst_table cascade constraints purge';
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN table_not_exists THEN
        NULL;
    END;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create table sst_table (col1 number, col2 number)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create index sst_ind1 on sst_table (col1)';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'create index sst_ind2 on sst_table (col2)';

    FOR l_index IN ind_to_drop.FIRST..ind_to_drop.LAST LOOP
        BEGIN
            sql_to_exec := 'drop index ' || ind_to_drop(l_index);
            dbms_output.put_line(sql_to_exec);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_to_exec;
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN index_not_exists THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('no index ' || ind_to_drop(l_index));
        END;
    END LOOP;

    FOR l_index IN ind_to_create.FIRST..ind_to_create.LAST LOOP
        BEGIN
            dbms_output.put_line(ind_to_create(l_index));
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ind_to_create(l_index);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('ERROR WITH ' || ind_to_create(l_index));
                is_all_index_created := FALSE;
        END;
    END LOOP;

    IF NOT is_all_index_created THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'PROBLEM CREATING INDEX');
    END IF;

END;
/

exit

When I execute my script through sqplus I have the ERROR below I don't understand
sqlplus xxxxx/yyyyy@zzzzzz @ubscls_6711.sql

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Wed Sep 25 17:04:11 2024

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

drop index sst_ind1
drop index sst_ind2
create index sst_ind1 on sst_table(col0)
ERROR WITH create index sst_ind1 on sst_table(col0)
create index sst_ind2 on sst_table(col2)
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: PROBLEM CREATING INDEX
ORA-06512: at line 49


Disconnected from Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production

Could anyone help me with fixing my issue. It's probably simple but just can't find the reason.
Thanks

Why do you create table in PL/SQL? Consider a GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE

Hello Wernfried, my script is just a unit test to validate the logic. The target table already exists

It is doing what you said it should... your question states that:


create an index that is failing should continue to create the remaining indexes to th the end


There is a comment in the code that says:

first index is wrong because col0 does not exist

The output shows:
create index sst_ind1 on sst_table(col0)
ERROR WITH create index sst_ind1 on sst_table(col0)

... so that index creation fails as expected (hiding the real error, which is unhelpful, as @Koen said); then it continues, and shows:
create index sst_ind2 on sst_table(col2)

... which apparently succeeds. So it has continued to create the remaining indexes.
You are using the flag is_all_index_created to keep track of any issues. That is being set to false by the expected failure. Then at the end of your code you have:
    IF NOT is_all_index_created THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'PROBLEM CREATING INDEX');
    END IF;

and that is the error you are seeing:
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20001: PROBLEM CREATING INDEX
ORA-06512: at line 49

You are getting an error because your code says to raise that error, so there isn't anything to fix, given that you want/expect the first index creation to fail.

At the start of the script you have
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

so your script will exit with code -20001, indicating a failure, rather then zero, indicating success. You might not actually see -20001 though, it may be mod'd to a smaller range; Unix-y scripts wrap around if the exit code is outside the allowed range, so you might see -33 or 233, for instance. (Which is a reason to avoid using that, as some actual error codes would wrap to zero and look like success... its safer to ... EXIT FAILURE)

If you just want your script to exit with a non-zero code but not raise/show the exception then you can use a bind variable to track the overall status, something like:
set serveroutput on;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;

variable exit_code number;

DECLARE
    index_not_exists EXCEPTION;
    ...
    sql_to_exec varchar(200);
    --is_all_index_created boolean := TRUE;

BEGIN
    :exit_code := 0;

    ...
    FOR l_index IN ind_to_create.FIRST..ind_to_create.LAST LOOP
        BEGIN
            dbms_output.put_line(ind_to_create(l_index));
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ind_to_create(l_index);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('ERROR WITH ' || ind_to_create(l_index));
                --is_all_index_created := FALSE;
                :exit_code := 1;
        END;
    END LOOP;

--    IF NOT is_all_index_created THEN
--        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'PROBLEM CREATING INDEX');
--    END IF;
    -- optional
    IF :exit_code != 0 THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('PROBLEM CREATING INDEX');
    END IF:

END;
/

--exit
exit :exit_code;

Instead of your current boolean flag, this sets the exit_code bind variable to 1 if an error occurs, and exists with that; and you'll still have the index-specific dbms_output messages you can review. The PL/SQL block no longer raises an exception, so you won't get the  ERROR AT LINE 1 in the output.

Thanks Alex for your suggestion
I changed the ERRCODE -200001 to -100001 and now I dont see the 'DECLARE ERROR at line 1: in the output which looks fine BUT the sqlplus return code is now 0 which is not what I want
With ERRCODE -20001, I have tis misleading message but at least sqlplus returned value > 0 that can be then interpreted correctly by my other program consuming it

But it's not a misleading message. Why do you think it is? One of the indexes was not created. You are raising the error to indicate that to whoever runs the script. (Also you can't change the error you raise to -100001, or even -10001 - either will cause a different error and your PL/SQL block won't run at all...)

I agree, it's just a détail but at the end it dors what I want thé script to do

@Simon - I've added a way to get a non-zero exit code without the ERROR message, which might be what you're trying to achieve.

oooh interesting...how?

I’ve already added it - look at the last edit, and the last section of my answer, using a bind variable.

thanks ! I'll test it immediately

thanks again this is exactly what I wanted to do

The script handles any exceptions that are raised but does not show what the error is. Have a look at this block in the script.
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('ERROR WITH ' || ind_to_create(l_index));
                is_all_index_created := FALSE;
        END;

What it does is:
If any type of error occurs, then print to the screen that ... there is an error.
That isn't very helpful. There are a couple of built in functions to give you more info. SQLERRM gives the error code and error description, SQLCODE will just show the error code, dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace shows the complete stack.
For your case, SQLERRM should probably be enough.
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN OTHERS THEN
                dbms_output.put_line('ERROR WITH ' || ind_to_create(l_index));
                dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);
                is_all_index_created := FALSE;
        END;


Thanks Koen for the hint... but I still don't understand why I have an error at the level of the DECLARE statement
ORA-00904: "COL0": invalid identifier
create index sst_ind2 on sst_table(col2)
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:

this is point I want to understand, my post was clearly unclear. Sorry for that

I see the issue, did Alex' answer give you enough info ?
